# Random "vertical jumps" while scrolling up in UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a UIViewController which includes a UIPageViewController which itself includes a UICollectionViewController.

Above the UIPageViewController: a UIView (named *pagerView*) which moves up or down depending on the vertical scrolling-offset of the UICollectionViewController.

Finally, the UIPageViewController's top anchor is constrained to *pagerView*'s bottom anchor.

The problem is that scrolling up is not continuous, the UICollectionViewController sometimes "jumps" (it can be a few hundreds of points.)

**In order to reproduce: scroll to the bottom (row 9) then start to scroll up and see how it jumps to row 7.**

The source of the UIViewController:

```
import UIKit

protocol ViewControllerChildDelegate: AnyObject {
    func childScrollViewWillBeginDragging(with offset: CGFloat)
    func childScrollViewDidScroll(to offset: CGFloat)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var pageViewController: UIPageViewController = {
        let viewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: [:])
        viewController.delegate = self
        viewController.dataSource = self
        return viewController
    }()
    
    private lazy var pagerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .brown
        return view
    }()
    
    private let pagerViewHeight: CGFloat = 44
    private var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0
    
    lazy var pagerViewTopAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        return pagerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = "xxx"

        view.addSubview(pagerView)
        
        addChild(pageViewController)
        view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
        pageViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        pageViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pagerViewTopAnchorConstraint,
            pagerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            pagerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            pagerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: pagerViewHeight),
            
            pageViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pagerView.bottomAnchor),
            pageViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            pageViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            pageViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        let viewController = CustomViewController()
        viewController.delegate = self
        
        pageViewController.setViewControllers(
            [viewController],
            direction: .forward,
            animated: false,
            completion: nil
        )
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    }
}

extension ViewController: ViewControllerChildDelegate {
    func childScrollViewWillBeginDragging(with offset: CGFloat) {
        lastContentOffset = offset
    }
    
    func childScrollViewDidScroll(to offset: CGFloat) {
        if lastContentOffset > offset {
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
            pagerViewTopAnchorConstraint.constant = 0
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { [weak self] in
                self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        } else if lastContentOffset < offset {
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
            pagerViewTopAnchorConstraint.constant = -pagerViewHeight
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { [weak self] in
                self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The whole code can be viewed in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/arielm/9ec77960f2db4067b6c259e8fa9ea874). There is also a [XCode project to download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14EShOfemw0RBWBq3i4cMCRqgtMZSN9FL/view?usp=sharing).

And also: a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ycaC5v7GAIEwXlKs_EVrFzMke6b6RvHY/view?usp=sharing) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Instead of bits and pieces, create a real Xcode project, zip it, upload to Dropbox etc then share link.

Comment: Ok, I've downloaded attached project, but don't see anything wrong with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2. Please attach a video of the wrong behavior and describe steps to reproduce.

Comment: @Asperi Yes, it's not easy to reproduce... I have updated the code to make it much easier. In order to reproduce: Scroll to the bottom (row 9) then start to scroll up and see how it jumps to row 7.

Comment: OK - I downloaded it and tried to (using iPhone 8 simulator). You never mentioned what device, whether its a real one or the Simulator. I just updated to Xcode 13.3 but like @Asperi I just don't see any jump. does it happen for you slowly dragging the scrollView, or do I need to flick it? The more info the better!

Comment: @DavidH It happens on Simulator (try iPhone 12 mini) and real devices as well. I'm using XCode 13.2.1. I also uploaded a video of the problem. Just drag to the bottom and and slowly try to drag in the opposite direction and you should see a big jump.

Comment: I give up. I tried on 3 simulators and a real device. No matter what I do it never jumps - smooth as glass. Perhaps it's that your device is running a non-USA version of iOS - mine is USA.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously strange happening in the video.

Comment: @livingtech It's not obvious in the video because it's better felt when experimenting it. Anyway, when you're at the bottom of the scroll-view, a single swipe-up gesture teleports you from row 9 to row 6 in a very short amount of time. What I call a "jump".

Comment: I could reproduce this, and I've posted my observations. Hope it helps you in some way.

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time with your project, I haven't found a fix yet but I believe I've found things which can point you towards a fix.

Here are my observations:

1. As you scroll your `collectionView` from `CustomViewController` up/down, you are using the updated scroll offset through `ViewControllerChildDelegate` to adjust `pagerViewTopAnchorConstraint`.
2. Adjusting this constraint also adjusts the height of your `pageViewController` which in turn adjusts your `CustomViewController`'s `collectionView` height
3. Adjusting the `collectionView`'s height can cause jumps in its `contentOffset` depending on its current offset. Here's an answer which explains this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21787754/9293498

   Just to fact-check this, you can comment the parts where you update your `pagerViewTopAnchorConstraint`, and you'll notice that doing so will get rid of the 'jumps'
4. To further verify if this was indeed the case, I created two KVO observers: One for the collectionView's `contentSize` and the other for collectionView's `contentOffset` as such:

   ```
    contentSizeObserver = collectionView.observe(\.contentSize) { [weak self] collectionView, _ in
        //Ignore the values on "Found you!" checks, as its relative to my device
        if collectionView.contentSize.height < 3000 {
            print("Found you!")
        }
        print("CONTENT SIZE SET: ", collectionView.contentSize)
    }

    contentOffsetObserver = collectionView.observe(\.contentOffset) { [weak self] collectionView, _ in
        //Ignore the values on "Found you!" checks, as its relative to my device
        if collectionView.contentOffset.y < 1460 {
            print("Found you!")
        }
        print("CONTENTOFFSET SET: ", collectionView.contentOffset)
    }
   ```

   where I noticed I could catch the 'jumps' with breakpoints based on the values in my "Found you!" checks. Basically, when you reach Row 9 and try to scroll up, there are two things happening whenever a 'jump' is about to happen:

   - Your `collectionView`'s `contentOffset` gets updated based on the value from `collectionView.contentSize.height - collectionView.frame.height` which I'm guessing is attributed to the frame change
   - For some reason, your `collectionView`'s `contentSize` also gets a massive drop/rise in height (I'm talking 1000s) which is far from your `pager`'s height (which is 44)

   These couple changes added together is what we notice as a 'jump' which sorts itself out after some recursive calls during frame change.

Comment: Thank you @Lokesh SN for spending some time. Too bad you couldn't find a solution, but at least you showed that I'm not hallucinating with the "jumps" I was describing. I will accept this answer in 30 minutes if no one else has answered  some more valid answer, for you to get the bounty.

Comment: @ArielMalka Was not expecting the bounty, thank you! I feel like you're definitely a lot closer to the solution now that we kinda know the 'what' and 'how' behind the problem. Adding those observers for experimentations helps a lot on understanding the jumps(certainly did for me), good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the video provided, the issue seems to be due to the implementation of reusable cells.

When you first launch the app, there would be n cells (4 in your case) which are created as n instances. At this point, the n instances are in memory. when you scroll down, you don't see any issue cause the number of cells on screen reduces but still you are not creating any cells on the spot. On the other hand, when scrolling upward, you have n=2 cells and you suddenly need more when scrolling which creates the missing cells at the spot and causes the lagging jumps.

In a typical tableview, the number of visible cells is constant, such that you will always cache the same number in memory and reuse it when it goes beyond the screen.

**To sum it up:**
going from n to n -> no issue, you cache probably n+1 so you always have cells to reuse
going from n to k (k < n) -> no issue, you'll reduce the cached cell as you scroll
going from n to k (k > n) -> causes lagging, you'll have to create the reusable cells on the spot or reuse whatever already shown on screen while you can

You can fix this by simply replacing `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell` with you own array where you store the initiated cells and reuse them. This of course will require special handling but I believe it would fix your issue

Hope this explanation helps :)